# Convertion to String in the DF Pandas and behaviour of `in` operator with Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types

I have some pandas DF. As usually the data are of the Object type.

Now I want do next convertion:

```
df.A = df.A.astype(int)
df.B = df.B.astype(float)
df.C = df.C.astype(str)
```

This doesn't work for string convertion... Output is:

```
df.dtypes
df.A int64
df.B float64
df.C object
```

What is the fault in convertion and how I can convert to String? Probably else - I want have some general code, probably future String column doesn't have some values (just empty objects), could be this a problem?

What I actually want:

My df.C looks like here:

```
0 "test1"
1 "test2"
2 "test3"
....
```

Now, Im sure that I have Object "test1" (I canb just open the column and I see this value)
After I use

```
"test1" in df.C
```

I get `False` How is it possible? Some idea, probably I have to convert my column to array or list and search in array or list?

Comment: `Object` is the generic dtype that covers `String` also, have you inspected the data, you should find that it is in fact `String`

Comment: ok, but when I open my column df.C and take some object from this column (for example 'teststring'), I get False for 'teststring' in df.C... How is it possible?

Comment: show your code, I don't understand, also some data to reproduce your problem

Comment: ok, I describe my problem above. This is all, what I want to ask

Comment: That is the wrong way to test if your string is present in your series you should do `df.C.isin["test1"]`

Comment: `astype` converts the dtype (if it can) of the elements in the series, it doesn't return the target dtype

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't know this function. Thank you very much

Comment: You can also pass a regexp/pattern to [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/api.html#string-handling)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your question about `in`:

As far as I can see, `pandas.Series` doesn't have its own `__contains__` method (used to implement `in`) but instead inherits the method from [`NDFrame`](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/blob/master/pandas/core/generic.py).

Here, `__contains__` is implemented as:

```
def __contains__(self, key):
    """True if the key is in the info axis """
    return key in self._info_axis
```

That is, it looks in the index of the Series, not the entries. So for example `0 in df.C` is `True` because `0` is in the index. Conversely, `"test1"` is not in the index of your DataFrame so Pandas returns `False`.

As suggested in the comments, you could use `df.C.isin(["test1"]).any()` to see whether your string appears in the column.

Comment: Thank you for your information. It is always very usefull to understand, why exactly it doesn't work. I will accept your answer.